# Creating object keys under for-loop and manually

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Essentially I am creating object's key (year) using for-loop.
However, I would like to have it that the first key of the object will be the  `initial` key I manually created.

However, it ends up being pushed all the way to the last.

I have the following code:

```
const VEHICLE_YEARS = () => {
    const vehicleYears = {}
    vehicleYears['initial'] = 'Choose One'
    const startYear = 2013
    const endYear = new Date().getFullYear()
    for (let year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
        vehicleYears[year] = year
    }

    return vehicleYears
}
VEHICLE_YEARS()
```

it sends up like this:

```
{ 
  '2013': 2013,
  '2014': 2014,
  '2015': 2015,
  '2016': 2016,
  '2017': 2017,
  initial: 'Select One'
 }
```

Comment: What you are manipulating is an object, not an array. You can sort its keys first and iterate thru it.

Comment: You need to use a map or an Array.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: You can use map there (also you can use array). I provided an answer

Answer (score 1):

Simple Object does not provide what you want. You need [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) there.

You need this:

```
const map = new Map();
map.set('initial', 'Select one');
map.set('2013', '2013');
map.set('2014', '2014');
map.set('2015', '2015');
map.set('2016', '2016');
map.set('2017', '2017');
// etc
```

To iterate you can use `for..of`:

```
for (const [key, value] of map) {
  console.log(key, value)
}

// the result
initial Select one
2013 2013
2014 2014
2015 2015
2016 2016
2017 2017
```

If you iterate though map with `for of` it is guarantied that you will iter throught entries in order as you added them to the map. From docs:

> A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order — a for...of loop returns an array of [key, value] for each iteration.

Also, to iterate through entries you have [Map.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach).

```
map.forEach((val, key) => console.log(key ,val))
```